# TeamCity VSC checkout agent fails

Tags: git, teamcity

I started using TeamCity recently and I have a problem with checkout.
I get this warning:

```
Updating sources: Will use server side checkout: No supported VCS client found on the agent for vcs root 'mygiturl'. Details: Unable to run git
```

Git is installed on the agent VPS (windows machine). It is on the PATH as well and I also created what teamcity suggests the

```
%env.TEAMCITY_GIT_PATH%
```

Still getting this warning. Anyone knows why this happens. I am using latest TeamCity